# Older entries link within a category page

Tags: posts, php, categories, blog-page

I have set up a category called 'blog' and have all of my posts displaying from this category. I have selected to display 4 posts / page therefore there is a link at the bottom that says older entries. However, when I click on "older entries" button, it takes me to the store page. I think the url is causing this problem but I have spent the whole night last night to figure it out and I still haven't found a solution yet.

My website is: www.talis.com.au

My blog is: www.talis.com.au/?cat=28 (how to change it to www.talis.com.au/blog?)

Answer (score 0):

Go into Settings > Permalinks, and change the Permalink to a Custom Structure:

> /%category%/%postname%

You may need to update your Menu in Appearance > Menus also.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is what I've got after changing it. http://www.talis.com.au/category/blog

Comment: @Natalie: Hmm, I can see there are no entries on page 2.  I assume you have more than 4 entries in the Blog category?

Comment: Try creating a blank page called Blog, and then setting that page to be your posts page in Settings > Reading.  You'll have to add it to your menu also.

Comment: I've tried what you've mentioned above. However, what's showing on my blog page is the same as the home page. Is there anything missing when I am doing this? What I've done was:

Comment: 1. Created a php file called blog.php
2. Set up a page called "My Blog"
3. Used "My blog" as posts page
4. Added "My blog" to main menu

Comment: Hi, the blog.php is below, is there anything missing therefore my posts are not showing properly?

<?php 
/*
Template Name: Blog template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="cont_col">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--#content-->
<div class="grid_3 side_col_right">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>    
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: That looks okay Natalie.  In future, you can use pastebin.com to display code.

Comment: but now my blog page is the same as my home page. Do you know why?